# Android Sqlite Not Like Multiple Condition Issue

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to select the rows that match the passed *eta*, *category* and *class*, attributes but that doesn't contains the passed use1 and use2 attribute, so I have written this code

```
public Cursor getData(String use1, String use2, String eta, String category,
            String class) {
        try {
            Cursor c;
                c = mDb.rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM dbtable "
                                + "WHERE Use NOT LIKE ? AND Use NOT LIKE ? AND Eta LIKE ? AND Language LIKE ? ORDER BY Name",
                        new String[] { "%" + use1 + "%", "%" + use2 + "%", "%" + eta + "%",
                                "%" + language + "%" });
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            return c;

        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getDataCar >>" + mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }

    }
```

Unfortunately doesn't work, and doesn't exclude the rows that contains the attributes *use1* and *use2*, if I remove the two NOT LIKE conditions, works fine... so there is a syntax error with the two NOT LIKE conditions.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The first time the app crashed, with a generic SQLITE compilation error(but I cannot reproduce the error) in all the others attempt simply show me also the rows that match use1 and use2 attributes.

Comment: question is what are the params ... do they contain chars with accents(ą, ć, etc.) ?

Comment: are the two String "SUV" and "SPORT"... I have also tried to write directly "SUV" and "SPORT" in place of use1 and use2... with the same result

Comment: Ops... I have fix the issue... is caused by a whitespace in these two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
The problem is caused by a whites space in the column of database... the syntax is right.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE Use NOT LIKE ? AND Use NOT LIKE (NOTHING HERE) AND Eta LIKE ? AND Language LIKE ? ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I have miscopied the code...the cause is another